# Django - Actualizando multiples modelos desde un formulario - No guardado de datos en la actualización

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

Tengo un modelo de usuarios personalizado en donde manejo tres perfiles de usuario: `StudentProfile`, `ProfessorProfile` y `ExecutiveProfile`. Cada uno de estos modelos tiene relación con mi modelo `User` personalizado

Para estos tres perfiles, tengo tres formularios que heredan de `form.ModelForms`, en donde se generan los propios campos de cada perfil de usuario:

```
class StudentProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StudentProfile
        fields = ('origin_education_school', 'current_education_school',
        'extra_occupation')

class ProfessorProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProfessorProfile
        fields = ('occupation',)

class ExecutiveProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ExecutiveProfile
        fields = ('occupation', 'enterprise_name', 'culturals_arthistic','ecological')
```

Para acceder a esta vista de perfil de usuario, he creado este URL

```
url(r"^profile/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$",
        views.AccountProfilesView.as_view(),
            name='profile'
    ),
```

Adicionalmente, mi vista `AccountProfilesView` tiene el siguiente comportamiento:

Desde la vista basada en clase `AccountProfilesView` se están instanciando cada uno de estos formularios, según corresponda el perfil del usuario, de manera que si un usuario tiene el perfil `is_student`, se generará su formulario correspondiente y asi para los perfiles `is_professor` e `is_executive`.

Si un usuario tiene los tres perfiles (`is_student`, `is_professor` e `is_executive`) se crearan los campos de los tres formularios para sus correspondientes datos asociados a estos perfiles.

```
class AccountProfilesView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    # All users can access this view
    model = get_user_model()
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
    template_name = 'accounts/profile_form.html'
    fields = '__all__'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AccountProfilesView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.request.user

        if not self.request.POST:
            if user.is_student:
                profile = user.get_student_profile()
                context['userprofile'] = profile
                context['form_student'] = forms.StudentProfileForm()
            if user.is_professor:
                profile = user.get_professor_profile()
                context['userprofile'] = profile
                context['form_professor'] = forms.ProfessorProfileForm()
                # print ("profesor form is", context['form_professor'])
            if user.is_executive:
                profile = user.get_executive_profile()
                context['userprofile'] = profile
                context['form_executive'] = forms.ExecutiveProfileForm()
        else:
            if user.is_student:
                context['form_student'] = forms.StudentProfileForm(
                self.request.POST)
            if user.is_professor:
                context['form_professor'] = forms.ProfessorProfileForm(
                self.request.POST)
            if user.is_executive:
                context['form_executive'] = forms.ExecutiveProfileForm(
                self.request.POST)
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data(form=form)
        user = self.request.user
        user = form.save()
        if user.is_student:
            student = context['form_student'].save(commit=False)
            student.user = user
            student.save()
        if user.is_professor:
            professor = context['form_professor'].save(commit=False)
            professor.user = user
            professor.save()
        if user.is_executive:
            executive = context['form_executive'].save(commit=False)
            executive.user = user
            executive.save()
        return super(AccountProfilesView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Y en mi template, tengo la siguiente pequeña logica:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if userprofile.user.is_student %}
        <div align="center"><i>My Student Profile data</i></div>
            {% bootstrap_form form_student %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if userprofile.user.is_professor %}
        <div align="center"><i>My Professor Profile data</i></div>
            {% bootstrap_form form_professor %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if userprofile.user.is_executive %} 
        <div align="center"><i>My Executive Profile data</i></div>  
            {% bootstrap_form form_executive %}
    {% endif %}

    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-default">
</form>
```

Los formularios se despliegan acorde al perfil del usuario, pero  lo que me sucede es que los formularios no guardan nada a la base de datos cuando hago el submit ... y además el `success_url` se comporta todo loco pues no me redirige al URL que quiero que es el `dashboard/`, sino que se queda en ese mismo template, pero pierdo la acción de estar loguedo con mi usuario,es decir me deja sin accion al LoginRequiredMixin().

En l ela sobreescritura que realizo del método `form_valid()` es en donde tengo la instrucción para grabar los datos de los formularios correspondientes.

Existe algo mal planteado en la sobreescritura del metodo `form_valid()` ?

---

---

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

---

---

Acorde a la respuesta dada por [@German-Alzate](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15252/german-alzate) y su recomendación de utilizar una vista basada en función, quisiera complementar algunos detalles de mi escenario y preguntar algunas cosas que me surgen a partir de su implementación dada:

En mi modelo Users personalizdo tengo los métodos `get_student_profile()`,`get_professor_profile()` y `get_executive_profile()` para obtener los datos de cada usuario en mis vistas. Están de la siguiente forma:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_professor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_executive = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_student_profile(self):
        student_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'studentprofile'):
            student_profile = self.studentprofile
        return student_profile

    def get_professor_profile(self):
        professor_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'professorprofile'):
            professor_profile = self.professorprofile
        return professor_profile

    def get_executive_profile(self):
        executive_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'executiveprofile'):
            executive_profile = self.executiveprofile
        return executive_profile
```

---

**Adición a la actualización**

---

Cuando creo un usuario con cualquier perfil `is_student`, `is_professor`, `is_executive` tengo un signal que hace que de manera automática tome el valor del campo `username` y lo guarde en el campo `slug` del modelo `User`

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def post_save_user(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    slug = slugify(instance.username)
    User.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk).update(slug=slug)
```

De esta manera utilizo ese campo `slug` para mostrarlo en el url de preferencias y de perfil de cada usuario.

Y cada perfil de usuario tiene su propio modelo relacionado con el modelo `User`, ademas de un campo slug, que toma el valor del `username` de su propio usuario relacionado en el modelo `User`.

Es de esta forma que en el modelo `User`, sobreescribo el metodo `save()` para indicar que el campo `username` de un usuario que se esta creando, sea igual en su valor al campo `slug` del perfil que tomara ese usuario (`StudentProfile`, `ProfessorProfile`, `ExecutiveProfile`):

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = super(User,self).save(*args,**kwargs)

        # Creating an user with student, professor and executive profiles
        if self.is_student and not StudentProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists() \
            and self.is_professor and not ProfessorProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists() \
            and self.is_executive and not ExecutiveProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():
            student_profile = StudentProfile(user=self)
            student_slug = self.username
            student_profile.slug = student_slug

            professor_profile = ProfessorProfile(user=self)
            professor_slug = self.username
            professor_profile.slug = professor_slug

            executive_profile = ExecutiveProfile(user=self)
            executive_slug = self.username
            executive_profile.slug = executive_slug

            student_profile.save()
            professor_profile.save()
            executive_profile.save()
```

Y los modelos de cada perfil (`StudentProfile`, `ProfessorProfile`, `ExecutiveProfile`):
 son:

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    origin_education_school = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    current_education_school = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    extra_occupation = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class ProfessorProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,blank=True)


class ExecutiveProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,      on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,blank=True)
```

Digo esto para ilustrar en mi código que tengo un campo slug en el modelo `User` que toma el valor del campo username y tengo un campo `slug` en cada perfil de usuario para efectos del url de perfil `profile/<slug>` con el que visualizo los n formularios que necesito de perfil

Pero en nuestra vista basada en funcion `account_profiles_view()` lo que se hace es volver a grabar esos datos de perfiles, o crear una nueva instancia de usuario al que pertenecen esos perfiles, dado que al momento de ir y editarlos, no los estoy actualizando sino que el sistema intenta crear un registro adicional con el mismo `id` o `pk` y produce un `IntegrityError` y es obvio, porque en ningun momento decimos que estamos actualizando ¿cierto?

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "accounts_studentprofile_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(14) already exists.
```

Resulta que ese `(user_id)=(14)` es el id o clave primaria de ese usuario en mi modelo `User`, pero en mi modelo de `StudentProfile` (dado que tiene ese perfil) tiene un `id=7` en ProfessorProfile tiene un `id=8` y en ExecutiveProfile tiene un `id=7`

Como lo que deseo es que mi funcion `account_profiles_view()` me permita actualizar los datos de perfil de un usuario sin importar cuales sean sus perfiles, entonces lo que creo (si no estoy equivocado claro) que debo hacer es actualizar el registro de perfiles de ese usuario de alguna manera interpretando el id de usuario que venga en el request, algo como esto ¿? :

```
User = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
```

Es decir que mi funcion `account_profiles_view()` tendría como parámetro un atributo `pk` además del request y que esa actualización debería hacerla después de que verifique que la operación será un método `POST`

La cuestión es que no tengo claro como hacerla y creo que finalmente mi función `account_profiles_view()` quedaría así acorde a como la has venido construyendo adicionando lo de la posibilidad de actualizar el registro de usuario para sus perfiles:

```
@login_required
# No tengo claro si con estos tres parámetros, se supone que si
# porque el slug lo necesito si o si para visualizar el perfil 
def account_profiles_view(request, slug, pk):
    user = request.user
    _forms = []
    if user.is_student:
        profile = user.get_student_profile()

        _forms.append(forms.StudentProfileForm)
    if user.is_professor:
        profile = user.get_professor_profile()
        _forms.append(forms.ProfessorProfileForm)
    if user.is_executive:
        profile = user.get_executive_profile()
        _forms.append(forms.ExecutiveProfileForm)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formularios =[Form(data = request.POST) for Form in _forms]
        if all([form.is_valid() for form in formularios]):
            for form in formularios:
                # No tengo claro como incluir esta parte del update
                # y como indicarla en las operaciones posteriores que
                # me explicabas
                user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
                profile = form.save(commit=False)
                profile.user = user
                profile.save()
            return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        formularios = [Form() for Form in _forms]
    data = {form.__class__.__name__.__str__().lower(): form for form in formularios}
    data['userprofile'] = profile
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile_form.html', data,)
```

De momento mi resultado al intentar "actualizar" el perfil de un usuario es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y es obvio porque no hago una actualización, pero si el problema esta en la linea del `profile.save()` pero si hago que la variable `profile` tome el valor del `user` que tiene el update del `pk = pk` , la cosa funcionaría?

Es algo que no estoy seguro, lo efectue, pero quise compartirtelo para tu orientación si es posible, dado que no resulta

**Fin de la adición a la actualización**

Hago uso de estos métodos en mis vistas en el momento en que evaluo cada request, de que tipo de usuario es, para asi mismo llamar su perfil, de esta manera y buscar de alguna manera enviar estos datos al template, sea  mediante algún contexto/diccionario o utilizando la función `render()` como sería el caso de que hicieramos todo en una vista basada en función.

Sería algo como esto lo que seguiría haciendo

```
if user.is_student:
    profile = user.get_student_profile()
    _forms.append(forms.StudentProfileForm)
if user.is_professor:
    profile = user.get_professor_profile()
   _forms.append(forms.ProfessorProfileForm)
if user.is_executive:
    profile = user.get_executive_profile()
    _forms.append(forms.ExecutiveProfileForm)
return render({'userprofile':profile})
# Aquí ¿enviaría los datos de perfil de un usuario
# en caso de tener los tres perfiles?
```

En tal caso, la vista basada en función y acorde a lo que German planteaba en su respuesta, quedaría asi:

```
@login_required
def account_profiles_view(request, slug):
    user = request.user
    _forms = []
    if user.is_student:
        profile = user.get_student_profile()

        _forms.append(forms.StudentProfileForm)
    if user.is_professor:
        profile = user.get_professor_profile()
        _forms.append(forms.ProfessorProfileForm)
    if user.is_executive:
        profile = user.get_executive_profile()
        _forms.append(forms.ExecutiveProfileForm)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formularios =[Form(data = request.POST) for Form in _forms]
        if all([form.is_valid() for form in formularios]):
            for form in formularios:
                profile = form.save(commit=False)
                profile.user = user
                profile.save()
            return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        formularios = [Form() for Form in _forms]
    data = {form.__name__.__str__.lower(): form for form in formularios}
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile_form.html', data, {'userprofile':profile})
```

Y en mi template, no se si estoy llamando de manera adecuada cada
instancia de formulario enviada desde la vista:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if userprofile.user.is_student %}

        <div align="center"><i>My Student Profile data</i></div>
            {% bootstrap_form studentprofileform %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if userprofile.user.is_professor %}
            <div align="center"><i>My Professor Profile data</i></div>
            {% bootstrap_form professorprofileform %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if userprofile.user.is_executive %} 
            <div align="center"><i>My Executive Profile data</i></div>  
            {% bootstrap_form executiveprofileform %}
        {% endif %}
        <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-default">
</form>
```

Cuando hago una prueba de mi url profile/username

```
url(r"^profile/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$",
        views.account_profiles_view,
            name='profile'
    ),
```

Veo este error:

```
File "/home/bgarcial/workspace/ihost_project/accounts/views.py", line 233, in account_profiles_view
    data = {form.__name__.__str__.lower(): form for form in formularios}
  File "/home/bgarcial/workspace/ihost_project/accounts/views.py", line 233, in <dictcomp>
    data = {form.__name__.__str__.lower(): form for form in formularios}
AttributeError: 'StudentProfileForm' object has no attribute '__name__'
[10/Apr/2017 18:43:40] "GET /accounts/profile/zidane/ HTTP/1.1" 500 86615
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Viendo el traceback veo que el inconveniente se referencia a la forma en como se están enviando al template en las instancias de formularios creadas en el diccionario `data`

No estoy muy familiarizado con la forma en como llevar a cabo el concepto
de compresión de listas y diccionarios (que creo que es la forma en como
lo estas haciendo ¿cierto?, me corriges si me equivoco por favor) pero entiendo que lo que se hace aquí es:

si la operación de `request` de un usuario es `POST`, se genera una lista
con todos los forms en donde se haya hecho dicha operación (es decir si esta en uno o dos o los tres perfiles de campos de formularios ).

Acto seguido, si todos los formularios contenidos en esa lista son validos
`if all([form.is_valid() for form in formularios]): ...`
Itere sobre cada uno y guardelos

Y por ultimo se forma el diccionario `data` en donde se envia cada instancia del formulario tomando su nombre respectivo, convirtiendolo a minúsculas y como son tres formularios se itera sobre la lista con todos los formularios generados.

Entiendo, que eso es lo que se hace aquí ¿verdad?
`data = {form.__name__.__str__.lower(): form for form in formularios}`

Y es bastante coherente y con sentido el planteamiento e implementación.
La cosa es que al obtener el mensaje de:

`AttributeError: 'StudentProfileForm' object has no attribute '__name__'`

No acabo de entender porque para tomar el nombre sería `'__name__'` pues creo que fue una convención que utilizaste para ilustrarme acerca de como sería la solución, y que en lugar de `__name__` para tomar un nombre como el que se intenta, ¿el sistema esta buscando o debe buscar un atributo que este en los formularios cuando fueron definidos?

Es decir ¿cualquiera de los campos de cada formulario que venga?
Pero no le hayaría sentido poner un nombre de campo, dado que en cad request de url `profile` pueden venir o `StudentProfileForm` o `ProfessorProfileForm` o `ExecutiveProfileForm`, pero cada uno tiene nombres propios de campos.

Por esta razón es que veo que en el planteamiento e implementación German intenta darle que el nombre de clave para el formulario que se envie sea el nombre del mismo y en minusculas para llamarlo en el template, lo que tiene sentido, pero entonces el problema de `AttributeError: 'StudentProfileForm' object has no attribute '__name__'` que no acabo de comprender.

Pero que veo que con su planteamiento voy un paso mas cerca de obtener la solución, dado que en el request en el traceback estan todos los campos de los formularios que se envian.

Comment: Bueno, para empezar, yo no creeria que estuvieras entrando a form_valid, si no a form_invalid, ya que en las CBV tienes usualmente un formulario por defecto, o puedes indicar uno, en este caso tienes 3, django no recomienda usar 3 formularios en una CBV, mejor usa funciones, y tienes todo un poco mas controlado, ahora, en el caso que quieras seguir usando clases, te recomendaria quitar el campo field, agregar un atributo form, con un formulario por defecto, y de acuerdo al usuario que te venga en la peticion, cambiar el metodo `get_form_class`, por el formulario que mas te sirve

Comment: @GermanAlzate Entiendo, si decido la primera opción, Es decir, 

¿que mi vista basada en clase `AccountProfilesView` sea una vista basada en funcion en donde se instancien cada uno de los tres formularios según sea el caso de quien venga el request y que la validacion de cada uno de los formularios sea en un método post? 

Más o menos fue lo que te entendí amigo.

Lo otro que me surge es: 
¿Cómo puedo capturar el request de un usuario en una `function based view`?

Comment: He editado la respuesta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La mejor opción como te comentaba en los comentarios, es hacer de tu CBV un FBV donde tendrías mas control, por algunos temas que te comentare mas adelante, de modo que quedaría algo como así:

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@login_required
def account_profile_view(request):
  user = request.user  # aquí capturas el usuario que viene de la peticion
  _forms = []
  if user.is_student:
    _forms.append(forms.StudentProfileForm)
  if user.is_professor:
    _forms.append(forms.ProfessorProfileForm)
  if user.is_executive:
    _forms.append(forms.ExecutiveProfileForm)

  if request.method == 'POST':
    formularios = [Form(data=request.POST) for Form in _forms]
    if all([form.is_valid() for form in formularios]):
      for form in formularios:
        profile = form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = user
        profile.save()
      return redirect('dashboard')
  else:
    formularios = [Form() for Form in _forms]
  data = {form.__class__.__name__.__str__().lower(): form for form in formularios}
  return render(request, 'accounts/profile_form.html', data)
```

Como ves, no me metí con el método `get_user_profile` porque no se lo que hace cada método, pero esto es una forma de verificar todos los formularios, y los recogerias desde el template como `{{ studentprofileform }}` tendrías todo más controlado. Esta forma es un poco automatizada, podrías hacerla mas manual y personalizada, que igual trabajarás mejor. Asegurate de mostrar los errores de los formularios para los usuarios desde el template, para que siempre lleguen los formularios adecuadamente llenos.

Ahora, en una CBV, el proceso es un tanto diferente, ya que las CBV estan diseñadas para usar un solo formulario, en tu caso usarás tantos formularios como permisos tenga el usuario, por lo que no es muy cómodo. Solo para darte una idea de lo que seria trabajar esto en CBV sería algo así:

views.py

```
class AccountProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
  # All users can access this view
  model = get_user_model()
  success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
  template_name = 'accounts/profile_form.html'
  # fields = '__all__' No necesitarias esto
  form_class = forms.StudentProfileForm

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(AccountProfilesView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    user = self.request.user

    if user.is_student:
      context['form_class'] = forms.StudentProfileForm(
      self.request.POST)
    if user.is_professor:
      context['form_class'] = forms.ProfessorProfileForm(
      self.request.POST)
    if user.is_executive:
      context['form_class'] = forms.ExecutiveProfileForm(
      self.request.POST)
    return context

  def get_form_class(self):
    return self.get_context_data()['form_class']
```

Porque al momento de hacer un POST, las CBV solo verificaran el formulario que obtengan por medio de `get_form_class` y ese formulario será el único que van a proceder a validar. Se puede llegar a validar los 3 formularios a la vez, pero tendrías que sobreescribir muchas partes de código y lo mas sencillo y rápido, será usar un FBV.

Cualquier duda, comenta.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Actualicé la parte donde te arrojaba error:

```
form.__name__.__str__.lower()
```

Lo cambié por:

```
form.__class__.__name__.__str__().lower()
```

Que básicamente para responder las otras preguntas, todo en python es un objeto, y la forma de crear objetos es mediante una clase, a la cual desde una instancia, se puede acceder mediante la propiedad 'magica' o 'privada' `__class__`, recuerda que este retorna la clase sin mas, y esta clase, por defecto tiene otra propiedad privada llamada `__name__` el cual te retorna el nombre en string de una clase, que será el mismo nombre con el que la llamaste, es decir con el que creas la clase, el que va luego de la palabra reservada `class`, luego llamo a su método en string, para asegurarme que siempre retorne un string y llamo a lower, la idea de hacer esto es poder ubicarlo en un diccionario de python y que puedas acceder a ello luego de una forma mas facil y legible para el humano. Esto solucionaria el `AttributeError`

Lo de data, es un simple diccionario de python, el cual será las variables que el django internamente enviará al procesador de contextos y su motor de plantillas para hacer el render de los templates. Consta de llave: valor, en este caso en la compresión de listas, lo que estamos haciendo es algo parecido a esto:

```
data = {}
for form in formularios:  # sabemos que formularios tiene todos los formularios instanciados
  data[form.__class__.__name__.lower()] = form
  # ya con esto sabes que al diccionario data en la posicion de el nombre del formulario, le asignamos el formulario
```

La explicación de esta linea:

```
if all([form.is_valid() for form in formularios]):
```

Es que usted solo debería guardar datos en la base de datos, si TODOS los formularios que le envió al usuario están correctos, de no ser así, esta linea no tendría sentido y habría que replantearla. Por eso verifico primero que todos los formularios hayan sido llenados.

Para concluir, habiendo resuelto varias dudas, quería ayudarlo a aclarar la parte de los perfiles, la razón por la que hace un rato no hice nada con los perfiles es que usted los está sobrescribiendo, cada que entra en un if, lo sobrescribe de acuerdo a un valor, por lo que tendrá problemas en su código si lo deja así, análisemoslo, te planteo que soy un usuario que es estudiante, ejecutivo, y además profesor:

```
if user.is_student:
    profile = user.get_student_profile()  # en este punto, mi perfil es de estudiante.
    _forms.append(forms.StudentProfileForm)
if user.is_professor:  # acá vuelvo a entrar porque no hay un elif
    profile = user.get_professor_profile()  # en este punto no soy ya estudiante, si no que mi perfil es de profesor.
    _forms.append(forms.ProfessorProfileForm)
if user.is_executive:  # nuevamente no hay un elif, así que vuelvo a entrar.
    profile = user.get_executive_profile()  # y ahora la misma variable profile dice que es ejecutivo
    _forms.append(forms.ExecutiveProfileForm)
```

Si ves los comentarios, te darás cuenta que la variable `profile` depende de el orden en el cual hagas las preguntas de if, y siempre obtendrá el valor de el ultimo if que evaluó a True. Pero dejando eso a un lado, no sé que importancia le das al profile, sin embargo, la forma adecuada de enviar dicha variable a el template, es de esta forma:

```
data = {form.__class__.__name__.__str__().lower(): form for form in formularios}
data['profile'] = profile  # de esta forma ya se envia a tu template
return render(request, 'accounts/profile_form.html', data)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu orientación, muy ilustrativa. Me han surgido algunas dudas a partir de tu enfoque, y he realizado una actualización en mi pregunta original comentando en detalle las dudas. Si tienes la oportunidad de revisarla te lo agradezco altamente. :)

Comment: De nuevo funciono tu enfoque, en efecto ya se intenta guardar a la base de datos con lo que me ha dicho. En este momento lo que persigo con esta fbv es actualizar los datos de perfil y el sistema intenta es guardar un registro nuevo de usuario con el mismo id que ya tiene, por lo que sale `IntegrityError - DuplicateKey` He adicionado un título a mi pregunta original llamado **Adición a la actualización** detallando una posible solución que creo que es el camino pero no estoy seguro de como hacerla compatible con lo que me has compartido. Si la puedes chequear gracias y perdona mi atrevimiento

Comment: Empieza **Adición a la actualización** y va hasta **Fin de adición a la actualización** solo en caso tal. Gracias.

Comment: ok, para lo que planteas solo enviale al formulario cuando lo instancias un atributo llamado `instance` y su valor debe ser el perfil de el usuario para cada formulario

Comment: Entiendo, hay que indicarle a la instancia del formulario (o las tres instancias en mi caso) que tenga acción sobre el usuario actual que envía el request ¿verdad? La cosa es que no se si lo estoy haciendo bien. Mira en este pastebin porfa como lo coloco y el erro que obtengo https://pastebin.com/uY6p87n7  Sorry por las molestias.

Comment: En tu caso hasta que no soluciones bien lo de los profiles, sera muy complejo pasar la instancia, pero debe ser en la linea que haces `formularios =[Form(data=request.POST, instance=userprofile) for Form in _forms]`

Comment: Esto tiene que ver que con lo que me comentabas antes, y es que ya supero el error último, pero cuando hago combinación de perfiles para ser actualizados, solo me almacena datos en el último perfil escogido por lo de las sentencias `if user.is_student` .. `if user.is_professor`... `if user.is_executive` .. Debería establecer todas las combinaciones posibles para que almacenen todos ¿verdad? Aunque pienso que cuando tu me dices que "soluciones bien lo de los profiles" es porque en cada combinación debería enviar el número de perfiles que combine también? Es un poco mi análisis/pequeña confusión